# Calling a WinDLL in python with complex struct not working

Tags: ctypes

I am trying to call a WinDll from Python, which generally works fine for simple functions. My issue is that I need to pass in a pointer to a complex structure, which is not working. I am not able to define the arguments of the WinDll function.

The function declaration in c and the data types look as followed:

```
typedef struct VBLFileStatistics_t
{
    DWORD     mStatisticsSize;                   /* sizeof (VBLFileStatistics) */
    BYTE      mApplicationID;                    /* application ID */
    BYTE      mApplicationMajor;                 /* application major number */
    BYTE      mApplicationMinor;                 /* application minor number */
    BYTE      mApplicationBuild;                 /* application build number */
    ULONGLONG mFileSize;                         /* file size in bytes */
    ULONGLONG mUncompressedFileSize;             /* uncompressed file size in bytes */
    DWORD     mObjectCount;                      /* number of objects */
    DWORD     mObjectsRead;                      /* number of objects read */
} VBLFileStatistics;

( BOOL)   BLGetFileStatistics( HANDLE hFile, VBLFileStatistics* pStatistics);
```

Loading and getting the handle works fine.

```
import sys
import ctypes 
from ctypes import wintypes

GENERIC_READ         = wintypes.DWORD(0x80000000) 
INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1 

class VBLFileStatistics(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [
        ("mStatisticsSize", wintypes.DWORD),
        ("mApplicationID", wintypes.BYTE),
        ("mApplicationMajor", wintypes.BYTE),
        ("mApplicationMinor", wintypes.BYTE),
        ("mApplicationBuild", wintypes.BYTE),
        ("mFileSize", ctypes.c_ulonglong),
        ("mUncompressedFileSize", ctypes.c_ulonglong),
        ("mObjectCount", wintypes.DWORD),
        ("mObjectsRead", wintypes.DWORD)]

lib = ctypes.WinDLL('myDll.dll')

#( HANDLE) BLCreateFile( LPCSTR lpFileName, DWORD dwDesiredAccess);
lib.BLCreateFile.restype  = wintypes.HANDLE
lib.BLCreateFile.argtypes = [wintypes.LPCSTR, wintypes.DWORD]

handle = lib.BLCreateFile(b'test.blf',GENERIC_READ)
    if(ctypes.c_int(handle).value == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE):
        print("Error occured reading the file!!!")
        sys.exit()

#( BOOL)   BLGetFileStatistics( HANDLE hFile, VBLFileStatistics* pStatistics);
lib.BLGetFileStatistics.restype  = wintypes.BOOL
lib.BLGetFileStatistics.argtypes = [wintypes.HANDLE, ctypes.pointer(VBLFileStatistics)]

stats_obj = VBLFileStatistics()
success = lib.BLGetFileStatistics(handle, ctypes.pointer(stats_obj))
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 104, in <module>
    lib.BLGetFileStatistics.argtypes = [wintypes.HANDLE, ctypes.pointer(VBLFileStatistics)]
TypeError: _type_ must have storage info
```

I also tried setting `argtypes` to a void pointer  (`wintypes.LPCVOID`) and then passing a pointer to `stats_obj` for `BLGetFileStatistics`, which did not cause an error, but also did not work, since the `stats_obj` was still empty after the call.

Comment: It's `lib.BLGetFileStatistics.argtypes = [wintypes.HANDLE, ctypes.POINTER(VBLFileStatistics)]` (**capital *POINTER***).

Comment: @CristiFati thanks for the reply, you are right! I did not know that there was a diffrence between `pointer` and `POINTER`. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes. Does it work now?

Comment: Yes, is working now ;-)! Thx